# How Ward Identity indicate vacuum polarization correction?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, ward-identity

In Peskin & Schroeder Chapter 7.5 **Renormalization of The Electric Charge**, they mention that vacuum polarization correction is
$$
iM= (-ie)^2(-1)\int_{}{}\frac{d^4k}
{(2\pi)^4}Tr\bigg[\gamma^{\mu}\frac{(\require{cancel}\cancel{p}+\cancel{k}+m)}{(\cancel{k}+\cancel{p})^2-m^2}\gamma^{\nu}\frac{(\cancel{k}+m)]}{k^2-m^2}\bigg]=i\Pi^{\mu\nu}_2(p)
$$ 
and continue

> > The only tensors that can appear in $\Pi^{\mu\nu}_2(p)$ are $g^{\mu\nu}$ and $p^{\mu}p^{\nu}$. The [Ward Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity), however, tells us that $p^{\mu}\Pi^{\mu\nu}_2(p)=0$. This implies that $\Pi^{\mu\nu}_2(p)$ is proportional to the projector $(g^{\mu\nu}-\frac{p^{\mu}{p^{\nu}}}{p^2})$.

I can not see the connection of Ward identity and "the projector", indeed. What do they mean even by projector?

Comment: I upvoted this question as being the sort of subject matter which I'd like to see more of here, but I freely acknowledge that there are something like two or three different questions here and you should probably be very clear on what you're asking. The two statements in your quote imply the third as the first states that $\Pi_2^{\mu\nu} = A g^{\mu\nu} + B p^\mu p^\nu$ and the Ward identity then gives $p_\mu ~\Pi_2^{\mu\nu} = A p^\nu + B p^2 p^\nu = 0$, which for nonzero $p^\nu$ means $A + B p^2 = 0$. But I don't know particle physics well enough to explain the various Feynman-slash terms.

Comment: @ChrisDrost Thanks for the tip. I edit the question. BTW, I did not find the proper latex command for Feynman-slash notation. Anyone welcome to edit.

Comment: Concerning Feynman-slash, see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4389/2451

Answer (score 2):

**(i)** *"The only tensors that can appear in $\Pi_{\mu\nu}$ are $g_{\mu \nu}$ and $p_\mu p_\nu$"*: this is because these are the only rank-2 tensors available in the problem. $p_\mu$ is a vector on which the problem depends and $g_{\mu \nu}$ is the invariant tensor. Using only this two tensors (one rank-1 and one rank-2), you cannot construct any rank-2 tensors other than the specified ones.

**(ii)** *"$p_{\mu}\Pi^{\mu\nu}_2(p)=0$ implies that $\Pi^{\mu\nu}_2(p)$ is proportional to the projector $(g^{\mu\nu}-\frac{p^{\mu}{p^{\nu}}}{p^2})$"*: because of **(i)**, we have that $\Pi^{\mu\nu}_2(p)=(Ag^{\mu \nu}+Bp^\mu p^\nu)\Pi(p)$, and it is easy to convince yourself that $p_\mu\Pi^{\mu\nu}_2(p)=p_\mu(Ag^{\mu \nu}+Bp^\mu p^\nu)\Pi(p)=0$ implies that $A=1$ and $B=-1/p^2$ (if you don't absorb any arbitrary global factor into the $\Pi(p)$ as defined above).

**(iii)** *"What do they mean even by projector?"* You can write any vector as $p_\mu=\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}p^\nu+\left(g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{k_{\mu}{k_{\nu}}}{k^2}\right)p^\nu$, where the first term is the part of $p$ longitudinal to $k$ (you can see this by verifying that if $p_\nu=k_\nu$, we have $\frac{k^{\mu}{k^{\nu}}}{k^2}k_\nu=k^\mu$) and the second term is the part of $p$ transverse to $k$. In this sense, $\left(g^{\mu\nu}-\frac{k^{\mu}{k^{\nu}}}{k^2}\right)$ is the projector to the direction transverse to $k$.